# How to query posts with current or future date only

Tags: posts, wp-query

I want to only get posts with current or future dates, to show upcoming events.

Current arguments:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'event', 
    'meta_key'  => 'event_start_date',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);
```

This returns all the posts, including past events.

I read about `post_status` but it did not seem to work. I tried `'post_status' => 'future'` without success.

Comment: How is your `event_start_date` stored (`YYYY-MMM-DD`, `int`, ...)? Have a look at the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) docs on Custom Field Parameters.

Comment: It was a premade thing, it is stored as a longtext type.
the actual date is stored like this:   2014-11-14 20:00

Comment: Longtext or not, what is the format of the date string? See the first part of the following answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124163/21376

Answer (score 4):

adding the following arguments did the trick

```
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d h:i'),
      'meta_compare' => '>',
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out. Please remember to mark your answer **Accepted** once you're able to ([it's a 48-hour wait](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `'post_status' => array('publish', 'future')` to your `$args` will show only future published posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'event', 
    'meta_key'    => 'event_start_date',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future')
    );
get_posts( $args );
```